# Tensorboard Summaries Stuck at 0

Tags: python, tensorboard

I haven't found this anywhere; I can't quite wrap my head around how to add in scalar summaries in Tensorboard, so I decided to make the most basic example I think of, a line. Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.float32)

tf.summary.scalar("X", x)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess: 
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./logs', sess.graph)
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(1, 11):
        merge = tf.summary.merge_all()

        x = tf.add(x, 1)

        summary, x = sess.run([merge, x])

        writer.add_summary(summary, i)
    print("X = ", x)
```

No matter what I've tried to change, the scalar summary stays at 0 when I open up Tensorboard. Maybe I'm not understanding what the summary is? Maybe I'm creating it wrong? I honestly have no idea. Any solid documentation on Tensorboard summaries would be much appreciated as well. Thank you.

[image: Picture of summary result]

Answer (score 0):

`x = tf.add(x, 1)` means that now a python variable`x` will refer to a **new** Tensor whose value is larger by 1 than the previous Tensor `x`. So the Variable created in Line 3 -- say `Variable:0` --- will remain intact and not be updated, whose value is still 0. You are creating a new tensor at every loop step. Since the summary is still referring **to the variable `Variable:0`** whose value is always 0, not `x`, the resulting behavior is correct.

You should do like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.float32)

tf.summary.scalar("X", x)

increment_op = x.assign_add(1)        # <------- here
summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()   # <------- watch this too 

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess: 
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./logs', sess.graph)
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(1, 11):

        summary, x = sess.run([summary_op, increment_op])     # <----- here

        writer.add_summary(summary, i)
    print("X = ", x)
```

Plus, make sure that you do not create unnecessary tensors (e.g. merged summary) during the loop. So creating `tf.summary.merge_all()`  on the fly is also wrong.